# Función inversa en Python y Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

estoy programando en Python y utilizando la librería Sympy, estoy en manejo de funciones y necesito sacar fa inversa de cualquier función, sin embargo no encuentro en la documentación y otros sitios web como se puede hacer esto, quisiera saber si esto se puede hacer y si es así como seria.

Ejemplo:

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Symbol('x')
f = x ** 2

*****código para la función inversa******

salida: sym.sqrt(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionando la ecuación `y = f(x)`, buscando `x`:

```py
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Symbol('x')
y = sym.Symbol('y')
f = x ** 2
soluciones = sym.solve(sym.Eq(y, f), x)
```

Da las soluciones `-sqrt(y)` y `sqrt(y)`.